# connect to a port address via curl and php

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm developing a php site using CURL,but it only works on my local server and not on live server.It returns an error 'could not connect to host'

CURL iS installed on live server and i have tested that.

SSL is installed on live server and I am connecting to port 9301 using curl

ie;http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9301/test.

Here is my code:

```
    $request =  'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9301/test'; 
    // The request parameters 
    $context = 'something'; 

    // urlencode and concatenate the POST arguments 
    $postargs = 'xmlRequest='.urlencode($context);
    $session = curl_init($request); 
   // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '9301');


    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs); 
    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($session); 
   //echo curl_getinfo($session);   
    echo $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($session);
   curl_close($session); 
   echo $response;
```

From my testing it's clear that i can't connect to a port address via Curl. In order to connect to the port address, need to change any server settings?

Comment: You are using ssl but your address starts with "http"?

Comment: Could be that your host's firewall is blocking that port, you might want to check with them. Edit: Could also be that your host rejects requests that don't have a user agent present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '9301');
```

That is your problem. The handle isn't `$ch` in your case, but `$session`.

Just a typo I guess.

**In general:** Make sure you display ALL error during development. Log them or put them on screen.
You would have caught this one easily.